# Django urls.py + React router

Tags: reactjs, django

I built a Django API and a react frontend to consume the API. I'm using react-router and can navigate just fine until I refresh the page. I then get a `Not Found` error form Django.

I'm not sure how to set up these paths with Django so it knows what to serve.

**api/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.apiOverview, name='api-overview'),
  path('product-list', views.product_list, name='product-list'),
  path('product/<str:slug>', views.product_detail, name='product-detail'),
  path('images/<str:fk>', views.product_images, name='product_images'),
]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name='app'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**app.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Nav />
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/products/:slug" exact component={ ProductDetail } />
          <Route path="/products">
            <Projects />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <div className='container'>
              <Header />
              <hr />
              <h2 className="section-title">Featured Products</h2>
              <ProductsListHome />
            </div>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you deployed your app already, or are you still running it locally?

Comment: @JoshMerrian It's deployed

Comment: Is it deployed to netlify?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is deployed to Netlify, add a file called `_redirects` to your public folder. Then, add the following line to it:

`/* /index.html 200`

Comment: It's on Digital Ocean

Comment: Ok try it anyway